# For RealVNC viewer for android is it possible to have the cursor go to where you touch?

Tags: vnc

I'am using RealVNC viewer android to control my computer but I would like to make a left click where I touch with my finger.
Dragging the cursor around is tiring when you have to make a lot of clicks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [AVNC](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.gaurav.avnc/), an open source application for VNC connections available on F-Droid and it does exactly what you're looking for, clicking the screen performs a left click on the clicked position

Comment: Thanks, it helped. When I used RealVNC, sometimes the colour was weird (with stripes of different colours), the workaround I found was to set the image quality to high. In AVNC I didn't find this feature but (for now) the colour quality is fine as it is